# https redirect in .htaccess doesn't work on homepage

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I've recently activated SSL on a website (https://ledertid.com)

I use this in my .htaccess to redirect everything from http:// to https://.

This is my original .htaccess

```
# BEGIN WordPress

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Then I tried this **(Option A)**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

# BEGIN WordPress

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

The above option A returned the following error in the browser:
"ledertid.com redirected you too many times."

Then I tried this **(Option B)**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

# BEGIN WordPress

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

**Option C**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# BEGIN WordPress 
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L] 
</IfModule>
```

It works like a charm on all url's except for the homepage. So if you visit **http://** ledertid.com it doesn't redirect you to the https:// version.

Is something wrong with my Rewrite rules in .htaccess or am I missing something else causing this problem?

Thanks a bunch in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this in your `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

This will force HTTPs on every page including your homepage.

Comment: Hmm..

This didn't work. Broke the entire with too many redirects page somehow.

I did remove the other Rewrite but still didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Please give this a try

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Also try putting the entire block before the wordpress stuff. Not inside it.